# layer 3 switch with vlans and home router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, switching

I have a home wireless router let's say a cisco e2500 and a layer 3 switch with 3 vlans, how can I get them to comunicate?
vlans are like this

- 172.168.10.0
- 172.168.20.0
- 172.168.30.0

wireless has the default

- 192.168.1.1

and the layer 3 switch that connects to the wireless router has ip

- 192.168.1.2

Comment: You need to do it at the switch level, or flash the router with DD-WRT/OpenWRT and build VLANs in the router. The stock router firmware will not support it. I can't tell you exactly how to do it because you didn't state your switch make/model.

Comment: I probably will be using a layer 3 cisco switch for small bussiness, I think the model is sf 300, would reall prefer doing it at the switch level

Comment: Could be wrong, but I don't believe the Cisco Small Business series is capable of handling the L2/L3 routing needed for inter-VLAN routing at the switch level (the switch is the gateway for the devices), you would need a higher-end switch. Best bet is to flash the router with DD-WRT, build the 3 VLANs and assign a port to each VLAN, or tag all three VLANs to one port if the 2500  is capable of that, then ingress each VLAN at the switch level

Comment: My bad... it is capable of it: http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/GetArticle.aspx?docid=2cdc5822dd2f45ac83d992e58be3d2cc_Layer_3_InterVLAN_Routing_Configuration_on_300_Series_Manage.xml&pid=2&converted=0

Comment: great, but assuming I can do it on the switch, how would I do it? doing just some test on packet tracer right now, have the 3 vlans and the wireless router, vlans comunicate just fine, but can't access the router

Comment: You will need an "internet" VLAN, and build a route so all traffic outside of your 172.16.0.0/16 subnet routes to that gateway.

Comment: For any device other than the switch that you use as a default router, ensure it knows the switch is the route for those blocks.

Comment: that's probably where I'm lost, so I have to make another vlan apart from the other 3 and make some kind of a trunk port to the wireless router? sorry kinda new at this

Answer (score 0):

To enable inter-VLAN routing on Cisco Layer 3 switches, all you need to do is assign an IP address to the SVI for each VLAN with the following commands:

```
interface vlan vlan number
ip address address of the SVI
```

IP routing must also be enabled.  This can be done with the

```
ip routing
```

command

Internet routing can be done with a standard default route at that point.